# Soln Verification: the space of bounded sequences converging to 0 is complete with metric $d([x_n],[y_n]) = \sup(|x_{ni}-y_{ni}|)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I proved in class the space of bounded sequences with the same metric is complete, so I shall use this fact. How's my proof? BTW, regarding notation, let $x_{jk}$ refer to the $k$th element in the $j$th sequence.

Consider an arbitrary Cauchy sequence of bounded sequences converging to zero $\{x_1\}, \{x_2\}, \cdots$. We know by part (a) that such a sequence has a limit, let's call it $\{x\}$. We just need to show that $\{x\}$ converges to 0. We know by definition of convergence that for an error of $1/2m$, there exists an $N$ such that for $k \geq N, d(\{x_k\},\{x\}) = sup_i|x_{ki}-x_i| \leq 1/2m \Longleftrightarrow \forall i, |x_{ki}-x_i| \leq 1/2m$. Fixing a $k \geq N$, we know that for $\{x_k\}$, because this sequence converges to 0, there exists a $J$ such that for all $j \geq J$, $|x_{kj}| < 1/2m$. Thus, for $j \geq J$, we have $$|x_j| \leq |x_j-x_{kj}| + |x_{kj}| \leq 1/2m + 1/2m = 1/m$$

Comment: If you know the space of bounded sequences with the same metric is complete, then you don't need to get your hands dirty with Cauchy sequences again! You could try to show that the space of sequences converging to zero is closed in this bigger space. (Hint - consider $\limsup$ and $\liminf$, as functions from the space to $\Bbb R$...)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen So I say that if we have a Cauchy sequence of sequences converging to 0, since we know the space of bounded sequences is complete, I can just say we know a limit $x$ exists. Now I just need to show that $x$ is in subspace? i.e. that $x$ is a sequence converging to 0?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, and it should be fairly routine. The limit won't necessarily be the zero sequence by the way - I think that's why you were getting stuck (eg consider the sequence $x = (1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ...)$. Then in this space the sequence $x, x, x, ...$ converges to $x$.) The point of my comment about $\limsup$ is that I think if you know enough of the basic facts about metric spaces and continuous functions and so on, you can probably prove this without even having to write down a single $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen How's my updated proof? I wrote it in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you want to show that every Cauchy sequence $\{[x_n]\}$ in the subspace of bounded sequences with limit zero (let's call it $c_0$) has a limit in that space. Now, what does it mean to be in $c_0$? It means that given $[x] \in c_0$, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N>0$ such that $|x ^i| \leq \epsilon$ for every $i \geq N$. You write that you already proved completeness of $\ell ^\infty$, so consider $[x]$ the limit of $\{ [x_n] \}$ in $\ell ^\infty$. If $[x]$ didn't belong to $c_0$ then $\exists \epsilon_0 > 0$ such that $|x^{i(k)} |> \epsilon _0$  for an increasing sequence of $i(k)$. Now, since $[x_n] \to [x]$ in $ \ell^\infty$, $\exists $N such that $d([x],[x_n]) \leq \epsilon_0 /2$ for every $n \geq N$. But then we have an absurd. Indeed if the previous were true, then for every $k$:

$$ |x_n ^{i(k)}| \geq | (|x^{i(k)}|- |x_n ^{i(k)} - x^{i(k)}| )|\geq \epsilon_0 - \epsilon_0 /2= \epsilon_0 /2$$

by the reverse triangle inequality, which is absurd since $[x_n] \in c_0$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by notation, what's $x_n^{i(k)}$?

Comment: You are dealing with a sequence of sequences, or if you prefer a sequence of elements of $\ell^\infty$ which are themselves sequences of real numbers. I denote with $n$ the index of the first sequence (so, I am taking the $n$-th element of a sequence in $\ell ^\infty$) and with the superscript the index of the sequence of real numbers

Comment: What does the $i(k)$ mean?